# If this is not equal to? Then do this

Tags: c#

I'm doing a hangman game, and just started to created the random word that will generate new word that users have to guess however sometimes the random code will generate the same word that was used previously. My question is... is there a symbol or code that will say if random number is not equal to... do this block of code.

Here's my code...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rW = new Random();

        foreach (TextBox textBox in addTextBox())
        {
            textBox.Visible = false;
        }

        RW = rW.Next(1, 4);

        if (RW == 1) //Cat
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;

        }
        else if (RW == 2) //Elephant
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            textBox4.Visible = true;
            textBox5.Visible = true;
            textBox6.Visible = true;
            textBox7.Visible = true;
            textBox8.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (RW == 3) //Giraffe
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            textBox4.Visible = true;
            textBox5.Visible = true;
            textBox6.Visible = true;
            textBox7.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (RW == 4) //Monkey
        {
            textBox1.Visible = true;
            textBox2.Visible = true;
            textBox3.Visible = true;
            textBox4.Visible = true;
            textBox5.Visible = true;
            textBox6.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the `!=` (not equal to) operator, i.e. `if (RW != 1) ...`

Comment: I think the question was not written correctly Glen. As I understood, you just want to make sure not to use a word that has been used before. For that, you have to use a collection to keep history between button clicks. If that's what you're after, my posted answer should help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `!=` which is an [equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic list and once a word has been generated, add it to the list. Then just generate a new word until the generated word is not contained in the used words list. Also, for the if/elseif statements, i'd say to use a switch statement instead, it makes it more readable.

Also make sure the usedWords collection is outside your button event handler, and not declared inside, otherwise it will be reset everytime you click the button.

List usedWords = new List();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rW = new Random();

```
    foreach (TextBox textBox in addTextBox())
    {
        textBox.Visible = false;
    }

    RW = rW.Next(1, 4);

    while(usedWords.Contains(RW))
{
    RW = rW.Next(1,4);
}

usedWords.Add(RW);


    if (RW == 1) //Cat
    {
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = true;

    }
    else if (RW == 2) //Elephant
    {
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        textBox5.Visible = true;
        textBox6.Visible = true;
        textBox7.Visible = true;
        textBox8.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (RW == 3) //Giraffe
    {
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        textBox5.Visible = true;
        textBox6.Visible = true;
        textBox7.Visible = true;
    }
    else if (RW == 4) //Monkey
    {
        textBox1.Visible = true;
        textBox2.Visible = true;
        textBox3.Visible = true;
        textBox4.Visible = true;
        textBox5.Visible = true;
        textBox6.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. For reasonable approach to the actual problem. Also note that this code hands forever after all 4 words are used (need to check before entering `while...`). Better approach would be to select random word from list of not-yet-used words and remove used ones from the list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out ALexei, you're completely right. I did assume that the OP would be changing the random limits when actually applying the solution.

Comment: If I was to remove the word each time, how would I do this?

Comment: You initialize a list of available words when your Form loads, Glen, then each time the button is clicked, you select a random word from that list, display it (or whatever you want to do with it) and then remove it from the available list of words, to make sure it is not selected again. At some point you will run out of words, so you'll have to add validation to make sure you don't run your logic against a null selection.